# How to see texture with a "node viewer" using node wrangler addon

Tags: node-editor

I am trying to build a grungey texture and in order to see it I want to use a node viewer.  In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SAtFHBzEqAI) at minute 1:28 he talks about enabling node wrangler addon and then **control + shift** to **activate the vewier** when he adds a node. THAT control + shift does not work in Blender 2.76. Is this a version difference?

Comment: It works for me on Windows 7 in 2.76b. You need to be in Render Preview mode to see any change, but it should work as expected.

Comment: I'm on the same system, smae ver. and I can control+shift click 20 times and I do not get the viewer. Very frustrating.

Comment: Got it. One has to actually control+shift click the yellow color dot to make it connect and show the viewer. –

Comment: You should click *the node itself* with `Ctrl` and `Shift` pressed, afaik no need to click the yellow (or any) dot. To activate *another* node output socket (if any) click once more.

Answer (score 7):

As [mentioned by @mr-zak](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41437/how-to-see-texture-with-a-node-viewer-using-node-wrangler-addon#comment69026_41437):

Node wrangler uses <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left-Mouse</kbd> as default mapping. That means, you have to keep <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys pressed and <kbd>Left-Click</kbd> the node.